# Chrome Extensions were not restored from backup

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have installed a new SSD in my computer.

My old  HDD is still working and intact. I can access Windows in there still.

I have moved from `HDD Windows 7 32 bit` to `SSD Windows 10 64 bit`.

Then I have installed Chrome browser and replaced the `UserData` folder with the one from backup.

Everything (Favorites, Last Session etc.) seems to be restored properly, except the extensions.
None of them was restored.

These are all the extensions in the backup Extensions folder.

[image: All the extensions from within the Extensions folder]

Once Chrome is started, it empties the Extensions folder, resulting in none of them being installed, and I lose data among them.

[image]

My question is simple: **having all the extensions correctly backed up how can I restore them properly?**

Comment: I'm afraid StackOverflow is the wrong place to ask this question, since it's not dealing with developing extensions. [su] is a better fit.

Comment: @Xan, yes, but one who knows the mechanics of Chrome extensions development may know better how they work, their dependencies, and why it crashed this way. Anyway, I solved by syncing settings to Google accounts.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The solution for this specific case, in which I had access to my old system, was to:

```
1. start Windows 7 (old system);
2. open Chrome browser;
3. sync settings, extensions, passwords, history, favorites etc.
4. start Windows 10 (new system);
5. open and sync settings from Google account;
```

Unfortunately, if one doesn't have this option he may not have the same luck.